# Data in Relay not fetched when using it with react-navigation in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, relay, react-navigation

I'm trying to setup my app with Relay and `react-navigation`, following the hints that were discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/588#issuecomment-287499493). Also note that I used `create-react-native-app` to create the project.

This is what my setup looks like:

**App.js**

```
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/ciyeih9590fhl0162e5zh1z4h', {
    headers: {
    },
  })
)

const RootNavigationStack = StackNavigator({
  PokemonList: {
    screen: PokemonList
  }
})

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootNavigationStack />
  }
}
```

**PokemonList.js**

```
class IndexRoute extends Route {
  static queries = {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`query { viewer }`
  }
  static routeName = 'IndexRoute'
}

export default class PokemonList extends React.Component {

  render() {    
    return (
      <Relay.RootContainer
        Component={PokemonListRelayContainer}
        route={new IndexRoute()}
        renderFetched={(data) => {
          console.log('PokemonList - renderFetched', data)
          return <Text>Test</Text>
        }}
      />
    )
  }

}

const PokemonListRelayContainer = Relay.createContainer(PokemonList, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        id
        allPokemons(first: 10) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  }
})
```

The logging statement in `renderFetched` is being executed, but for some reason the `data`is empty:

```
PokemonList - renderFetched {"viewer":{"__dataID__":"viewer-fixed","__fragments__":{"0::client":[{}]}}}
```

Any idea what I'm missing in this setup?

Comment: Glad you solved the issue.  It looks like your implementation above is circular - PokemonList renders RootContainer, which contains PokemonListRelayContainer, which renders PokemonList, which renders RootContainer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue myself, so apparently the `PokemonList`, being my root component, didn't get access to the data that was requested - though I assume it actually was loaded, but due to Relay's data masking wasn't visible to the component.

The solution I came up with to wrap `PokemonList` in another component that would render the `Relay.RootContainer` and then go from there with my conventional Relay setup.

This is what it now looks likes:

**PokemonListWrapper.js**

```
class PokemonListWrapper extends React.Component {    
  render() {
    return (
      <Relay.RootContainer
        Component={PokemonList}
        route={new IndexRoute()}
        renderFetched={data => <PokemonList {...this.props} {...data}/>}        
      />
    )
  }    
}
```

**PokemonList.js**

```
class PokemonList extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        {this.props.viewer.allPokemons.edges.map(pokemonEdge => (
          <Text key={pokemonEdge.node.id}>{pokemonEdge.node.name}</Text>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }

}

export default Relay.createContainer(PokemonList, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        id
        allPokemons(first: 10) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  }
})
```

**App.js**

```
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/ciyeih9590fhl0162e5zh1z4h')
)

export class IndexRoute extends Route {
  static queries = {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`query { viewer }`
  }
  static routeName = 'IndexRoute'
}

const RootNavigationStack = StackNavigator({
  PokemonList: {
    screen: PokemonListWrapper
  }
})

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <RootNavigationStack />
    )
  }
}
```